# Delete class A and all related instance in other classes using reference

Tags: java, reference

I have 3 classes. Class A ,Class B and class C.

I have a class A and i want to pass same instance of A into class B and class C,ca n i found a way when i delete class A(instance used in C and B) that set to null in C and B by reference without need to set use setA(null).

Comment: What do you mean by *delete class `A`*?

Comment: I mean that i remove class A from session and set it to null

Comment: You can't remove a class from the program runtime... maybe you can remove an instance of a class, but not the class itself

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand you correctly.  Are you saying that you want a way to traverse the entire heap, looking for instances of class `A`, and null out all references to all of them?

Comment: No i want to remove instance of a class from the program runtime and set null automatically in all classes contains this instance

Comment: David,it is true but after a remove instance itself

Answer (score 1):

Use [WeakReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html)s.

In B and C, make your references to A like this:

```
public class B {
    private final WeakReference<A> myA;

    public B (A aToUse) {
        myA = new WeakReference<A>(aToUse);
    }

    private void doSomethingWithMyA() {
        A aToUse = myA.get();  // This returns null when the instance has been GC'd
    }        
}
```

Now, if the instance to A that you're deleting is the only instance of A that isn't a `WeakReference`, then that instance of A becomes eligible for garbage collection. Once it is garbage collected your `WeakReference`s will return `null`;

Answer (score 0):

No, If i am not wrong , You want that You want that after deleting Class A, Class Band C Should to Run assigning null to the Instance of A used, 
You Can not do that, Basically when you use a class say Class A in another class say Class B , the Class Loader for the Class A, if it is found then JVM proceeds to another steps, But if you have Deleted that class , the Class Loader will not be able to find that , and will throws exception , Class Not Found Exception,  or something Like that,

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding if you are passing the instance of Class A into B and C and you want that after deleting it this reference is set to null.

Note that first all the classes are loaded by class loader so at compile time the references are checked and if you delete the class A and surely you have declare the reference of A in B and C, so it gives you the compilation error type is missing something like that

Comment: @user2563277 have u got

Answer (score 0):

You need some managing mechanism, if you want to control links to your instance.
Without 3rd party solutions, easiest way to do it, is to provide intermidiate container object, which will control access to your instance.

Here is a basic example:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    DogContainer dc = new DogContainer(new Dog("Scooby-Doo"));
    Person shaggy = new Person("Shaggy");
    shaggy.setDogContainer(dc);
    Person dafna = new Person("Dafna");
    dafna.setDogContainer(dc);

    System.out.println(shaggy.getName() + " -> " + shaggy.getDogName());
    System.out.println(dafna.getName() + " -> " + dafna.getDogName());

    // Something happened with Scooby here. Say, a bus factor.
    dc.setDog(null);

    System.out.println(shaggy.getName() + " -> " + shaggy.getDogName());
    System.out.println(dafna.getName() + " -> " + dafna.getDogName());
}

static class Dog {
    private String name;
    public Dog(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public String getName() { return name; }
}

static class DogContainer {
    private Dog dog;
    public DogContainer(Dog dog) { this.dog = dog; }
    public Dog getDog() { return dog; }
    public void setDog(Dog dog) { this.dog = dog; }
}

static class Person {
    private String name;
    private DogContainer dogContainer;
    public Person(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setDogContainer(DogContainer dc) { this.dogContainer = dc; }
    public String getDogName() {
        Dog dog = dogContainer.getDog();
        return dog == null ? "Sorry, this person is not a dog owner" : dog.getName();
    }
}
```

Here we have three entities: a dog, a person and a dog container.
The person is the dog owner. But he has no direct link to the dog. It can interact with the dog only through the container.
So if you change link into container it will affect all persons.

The output is:

```
Shaggy -> Scooby-Doo
Dafna -> Scooby-Doo
Shaggy -> Sorry, this person is not a dog owner
Dafna -> Sorry, this person is not a dog owner
```

P.S. Also using of nulls is a bad practice, so it's better to use `Special Case` pattern to provide `Null Object`.